# getPastEvent in web3.js returns empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

I am working on `dogechain`.
I am trying to get `TokenLockerCreated` event on [TokenLockerManagerV1](https://explorer.dogechain.dog/address/0x016c1D8cf86f60A5382BA5c42D4be960CBd1b868/contracts) contract using web3.js.

This is event part on contract.

```
emit TokenLockerCreated(
      id,
      tokenAddress_,
      token0Address,
      token1Address,
      _msgSender(),
      token.balanceOf(lockerAddress),
      unlockTime_
    );
```

And this is `web3.js` part I used to catch this event.

```
      const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rpc03-sg.dogechain.dog"));
      const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(LPAbi, pairAddr);
      contract.getPastEvents("TokenLockerCreated",
        {
          fromBlock: 0,
          toBlock: 'latest',
        })
        .then(events => console.log(events))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

I tried `allEvents` instead of `TokenLockerCreated`, but they both returns empty array as `events`.

Comment: Did you check your HttpProvider?
If your provider is not correct, then it will return empty array.
Try other providers.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite common because of the range issue, the chains support a range, and it works with several other constraints as well.

this example is only for readme purpose, to get this working i suggest to use this,

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber((error, result) => {
    if (!error) {
        Contract.getPastEvents("TokenLockerCreated",{fromBlock:  result - 1000 ,toBlock: result},
        (error, events) => {
          // todo
        });
    }
});
```

the range is accepted upto 5000 in some chains and some use a limit of 1000, so using 1000,

this works in a range but never try to get past events from 0th block to till date,